# Adding date and dateinterval in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add date on php and this is my code:

```
$reading1 = 800;
$reading2 = 500;

$reading_diffrence = $reading1 - $reading2;

$date1 = date_create('2016-03-10');


$date2 = date_create('2016-03-15');

$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

$diff_date = $diff->format('%a');


$run_perday = round($reading_diffrence / $diff_date);

$sched = date_add($date2,$diff_date);


echo "<br>$diff_date</br>";
echo "<br>$reading_diffrence</br>";
echo "<br>$run_perday</br>";
echo "<br>$sched</br>";
```

I'm receiving an error of:

```
Warning: date_add() expects parameter 2 to be DateInterval, string given
```

How can I add `$date2` and my date interval `$diff_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the warning says, `date_add()` requires parameter 2 to be a DateInterval. If you look at the documentation for the `format()` method, you'll find that it returns a string. So when you run `$diff->format('%a')`, `$diff_date` is now a string.

You should try to simply do `$sched = date_add($date2, $diff);`

Here's a link to the manual for the `date_add()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: Another error comes up 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string'

Comment: probably this line `echo "<br>$sched</br>";` you need to change it to `echo "<br>" . $sched->format( '' ) . "</br>";`, replaceing `''` with whatever format string you want.